# if is home, check post type, echo if certain result? (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax

Hi i'm wondering if someone could help me with the correct syntax for checking for a post type when on the index feed, currently I'm trying this -

```
<div class="<?php if(is_home() )
{<?php if ( 'movies' == get_post_type() ) { echo 'textbox';}?> ;}?>">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for multiple PHP open tags.

```
<div class="<?php if (is_home() && (get_post_type() == 'movies')) { echo 'textbox';} ?>">    </div>
```

What I would probably do in this situation is clear it up a bit:

```
<?php
$class = (is_home() && get_post_type()==='movies') ? 'textbox' : '';
echo '<div class="', $class, '"></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
   // Default homepage

   } elseif ( is_front_page()){
     //Static homepage

   } elseif ( is_home()){

     //Blog page

   } else {

     //everything else

   }
}
```